# How can I append a calculated output to the end of a line in a tab-delimited text file using awk or sed in bash?

Tags: awk, sed

## Background

I am working with a tab-delimited text file (a GENCODE GTF file) and wish to calculate the difference between **columns 5** and **4** of each line, then append the result to the end of each line, respectively.

This is a sample of the 2,604,491 line file:

```
chr1    HAVANA  gene    11869   14409   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2";
chr1    HAVANA  transcript      11869   14409   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-002"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    11869   12227   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-002"; exon_number 1; exon_id "ENSE00002234944.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    12613   12721   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-002"; exon_number 2; exon_id "ENSE00003582793.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    13221   14409   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-002"; exon_number 3; exon_id "ENSE00002312635.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1";
chr1    HAVANA  transcript      12010   13670   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-001"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; ont "PGO:0000019"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002844.2";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    12010   12057   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-001"; exon_number 1; exon_id "ENSE00001948541.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; ont "PGO:0000019"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002844.2";
```

This is my desired output given the above sample (scroll to the end of both code samples to see the change):

```
chr1    HAVANA  gene    11869   14409   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; 2540
chr1    HAVANA  transcript      11869   14409   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-002"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1"; 2540
chr1    HAVANA  exon    11869   12227   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-002"; exon_number 1; exon_id "ENSE00002234944.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1"; 358
chr1    HAVANA  exon    12613   12721   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-002"; exon_number 2; exon_id "ENSE00003582793.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1"; 108
chr1    HAVANA  exon    13221   14409   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-002"; exon_number 3; exon_id "ENSE00002312635.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1"; 1188
chr1    HAVANA  transcript      12010   13670   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-001"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; ont "PGO:0000019"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002844.2"; 1660
chr1    HAVANA  exon    12010   12057   .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-001"; exon_number 1; exon_id "ENSE00001948541.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; ont "PGO:0000019"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002844.2"; 47
```

## My Attempt

Here is what I tried:

```
# this file has a header 5 lines long, so the calculation should start on the 6th line
awk 'NR>=6 {$10=$5-$4} 1' gencode.gtf > output.txt
```

This code replaces the `"ENSG00000223972.5;"` of `gene_id` with the difference calculation at the beginning of the 9th column (I hoped it would create a 10th column since this is supposedly a 9 column file). E.g.,:

```
chr1 HAVANA gene 11869 14409 . + . gene_id 2540 gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the value you want to the end of the record:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR>5{$0=$0 FS ($5-$4)} 1' file
```

Comment: Very elegant. Works perfectly, also. Thanks for the contribution @Ed Morton!

Answer (score 1):

**Best/revised answer based on comments:**

```
awk -F"\t" 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} NR>=6 {$10=$5-$4} 1' gencode.gtf > output.txt
```

---

**Original answer:**

Turns out, it was a simple fix.

The code that works requires a tab-delimiter qualification. I.e.,:

```
awk -F"\t" 'NR>=6 {$10=$5-$4} 1' gencode.gtf > output.txt
```

Output (scroll to the end of the code sample to see the addition of the calculation):

```
chr1 HAVANA gene 11869 14409 . + . gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; 2540
chr1 HAVANA transcript 11869 14409 . + . gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-002"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1"; 2540
chr1 HAVANA exon 11869 12227 . + . gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-002"; exon_number 1; exon_id "ENSE00002234944.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1"; 358
chr1 HAVANA exon 12613 12721 . + . gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-002"; exon_number 2; exon_id "ENSE00003582793.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1"; 108
chr1 HAVANA exon 13221 14409 . + . gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-002"; exon_number 3; exon_id "ENSE00002312635.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1"; 1188
chr1 HAVANA transcript 12010 13670 . + . gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-001"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; ont "PGO:0000019"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002844.2"; 1660
chr1 HAVANA exon 12010 12057 . + . gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-001"; exon_number 1; exon_id "ENSE00001948541.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "NA"; ont "PGO:0000005"; ont "PGO:0000019"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002844.2"; 47
```

*However*, I notice that the style of the file *does change* slightly. There is now **less space between fields** which seems strange. I don't believe it affects it's functionality, but it does decrease it's readability by eye.

Comment: I welcome alternative solutions that do not change the file at all, also. Perhaps there is a more efficient way to do the calculation and append it without altering the file at all.

Comment: You have to set the output field separator `OFS` also to a tab, or it is replaced by a blank.

Comment: This fixes it all. Thanks @BenjaminW.
```awk -F"\t" 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} NR>=6 {$10=$5-$4} 1' gencode.gtf > output.txt```

Comment: Glad you solved your problem, but in the future, please reduce the size of your data to capture the basic problem and one example of any corner cases. AND we didn't need to see data that scrolled off the screen to help you solve your problem. Good Q/A in that you included your code, so  just make your posting a little more compact in the future ;-) (please) ....  Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, Appreciate the feedback!! I will edit the size of the data examples to be shorter. So there is less clutter to scroll through :)